# JQuery document.ready firing in Firefox and MS Edge but not Chrome after Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, document-ready

An Ajax call is used to upload a file. This works fine. The done/fail/always promise callbacks are called. However, the document.ready function is being fired in Firefox and MS Edge. Chrome (correctly) does not fire the document.ready function.

```html
<div id="message" style="">[placeholder]</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('(document.ready) msg = ' + $('#message').html());

  $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    var posting = $.ajax({
      url: serviceUrl,
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      dataType: "text"
    });

    posting.done(function(data) {
      if (data.trim() == "") {
        alert('success');
        $('#message').attr('class', 'success');
        $('#message').html('Successfully processed file');
      } else {
        $('#message').attr('class', 'error');
        $('#message').html(data);
      }
    }).fail(function() {
      // Show default error on general failures
      $('#message').attr('class', 'error');
      $("#message").html(DEFAULT_ERROR);
    }).always(function() {
      $("#message").css('display', 'block');
      // Reenable "Submit" button and hide loader
      $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
    });
  });
});
```

The alert in the document.ready function pops up after the Ajax call in Firefox and MS Edge.  The change to the #message div contents are overwritten. Chrome (correctly) does not fire the document.ready function and leaves the #message contents alone.

Why would the document.ready event fire after an Ajax call and how do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: If you see the `alert()` again in those browsers it probably means that the submit button click is submitting the form and not sending the AJAX request (and therefore 'reloading' the current page). You're probably missing a `preventDefault()` on the `submit` event of the `form`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I added a "return false;" statement to the click() function and that fixed it.